# SAGA GIS ----> need to export shapefiles to SVG

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-10.1, saga, svg

I am trying to export three shapefiles to svg files but the problem I could not make these shapefiles polygon to black outlines to be export to svg files. How do I do that ?

I tried to run that in ArcGIS 10.1 but it failed.

HELP !!!

Robert

Comment: Once I exported them to svg, do I need to have third party photo editing software to change to color what I want, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapefiles don't store any information about how to represent the data, only the geometry and attributes of the data.

As best as I can tell, SAGA only allows you (using the 'Export to SVG' tool) to export the geometry of a feature, and doesn't allow you to change the appearance of the exported SVG.

You can export the layout of a map as SVG in ArcGIS using the Export Map tool.  If you're layout only consisted of a view of your shapefile(s) with the symbology you need, the resulting SVG should be appropriate.

See the [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sm00000004000000) for more information.